# Campo personalizado Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony-2, symfony

Como escrever um campo de formulário personalizado no *Symfony2*? Sendo que nesse formulário deve aparecer:

- Um campo de tipo *Dropdown* com o *label* Cidade;
- Um outro campo do tipo *number* ao lado com o *label* número da porta.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas opções:

1 - Colocar os campos manualmente dentro do form e pegar os paremetros via $request dentro do controller.

HTML

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  <select name='cidades'>
    <option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>
    {% for cidade in cidades %}
      <option value="{{cidade.id}}">{{cidade.nome}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Controller:

```
$request->request->get('cidades');
```

2 - Utilizar o modo padrão do Symfony e trabalhar o Form com ArrayCollection.

[Embed Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)